# Uninstall app then install new app programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application in which I need to manage a second application. There is an update to the second application but the apps were signed with different signatures so I have to uninstall the existing application first. I have both intents created, and they both work; however, one intent overrides the other. How can I wait until the uninstall intent finishes then call the install intent?

```
    if (source.getName().toLowerCase().equals("lastbox.apk") && installed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:org.xbmc.kodi"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(source), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is related to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046810/android-makes-activity-a-wait-for-activity-b-to-finish-and-returns-some-values). u should start an activity and wait for a result when activity finishes, it gets back to first activity onActivityResult. your code in onActivityResult won't run until activity finishes and go back with a result.