# Gathering multiple intent extras while saving the results during return to the main activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentservice

I'm having problems storing intent extras from my previous activity when I use another intent to open an activity and return the result.

Logic:

- Activity A: receive string from check box, uses intent hasExtra to pass to activity b
- Activity B: List of edit text fields with buttons to activity c
- Activity C: uses intent extra to get string and pass to another editTextField in activity b

Problem is that I keep losing the intentExtra from a to b.

I apologise if my description is not thorough, I'm new to Java.

**Activity A**

```
public class PipesInspection extends AppCompatActivity{
private static final String TAG = "PipesInspection";
ArrayList<String> pipesInspectionSelection = new ArrayList<String>();
Button nextButtonToPost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.residential_pipes_inspection_lv_selected);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting");
    initialiseWidgets();
}
public void initialiseWidgets(){
    nextButtonToPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButtonToPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String final_category_selection = "";
            for (String Selections : pipesInspectionSelection){
                final_category_selection = final_category_selection + Selections + ", ";
            }
            Log.v(TAG,"gotten text: " + final_category_selection);
            String selectedChoices = pipesInspectionSelected.getText().toString();
            Intent pipesInspectionIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PostAJobActivity.class);
            pipesInspectionIntent.putExtra("selectedChoices", selectedChoices);
            v.getContext().startActivity(pipesInspectionIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Activity B**

```
public class PostAJobActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "PostAJobActivity";
EditText jobTitle, jobDescription, jobLocation;
String location, title;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_a_job);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting");
    jobDescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_job_description);
    mapsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
    mapsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LaunchMapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
        getIntentExtras();
}
 public void getIntentExtras(){
    jobLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
    Intent intentLocation =getIntent();
    location= intentLocation.getStringExtra("location");
    jobLocation.setText(location);


    jobTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    Intent pipesInspectionIntent = getIntent();
    title = pipesInspectionIntent.getStringExtra("selectedChoices");
    jobTitle.setText(title);
}
}
```

**Activity C**

```
public class PlaceListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceListAdapter.PlaceViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private PlaceBuffer mPlaces;


public PlaceListAdapter(Context context, PlaceBuffer places) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mPlaces = places;
}

@Override
public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Get the RecyclerView item layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_item_place_card, parent, false);

    return new PlaceViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlaceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String placeName = mPlaces.get(position).getName().toString();
    String placeAddress = mPlaces.get(position).getAddress().toString();
    holder.nameTextView.setText(placeName);
    holder.addressTextView.setText(placeAddress);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentLocation = new Intent(v.getContext(), PostAJobActivity.class);
            intentLocation.putExtra("location",holder.nameTextView.getText().toString()+
                    ", " + holder.addressTextView.getText().toString());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intentLocation);
        }
        });

}
```

Comment: Are you sure pipesInspectionSelected.getText().toString() has the right value you want to pass?

Comment: @roostertech yes it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this article may be helpful
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

I am not sure I understand the problem correctly...activity A starts first and passes data to activity B which invokes activity C and gets data from it return to activity B which uses the data collected from both activities to do something
....If this is your problem you should not start activity C the normal way you should use `startActivityforresult()` form activity B to start activty C
and wait for it to finish then return to B with the data collected from C....starting the activity B from activity C will create new instance of B without having the data collected form A while using this way the instance of B with data from A will wait to C to finish and take the data from it in addition to that move the `getIntentExtras()` function inside the `onClick()`

Comment: activity b is the main activity to collect information from activity c and a, but the flow starts with activity A, you suggest in activity b i should try startActicityForResult instead of StartActivity(intent)?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i was able to add onActivityResult and i used startActivityForResult method to handle the intent from activity B to C, but i couldnt add "setResult" from activity c onClick of onBindViewHolder. let me know if i need to edit my code to show you? @Ahmad-Rajab

Comment: read this question it has an example that helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046810/android-makes-activity-a-wait-for-activity-b-to-finish-and-returns-some-values

Comment: you still have a problem? @T-lang

Comment: yes i do, @ahmad-rajab, i'm unable to setResult in the adapter(onBindViewHolder) so im looking for a way to do that.

Comment: why don't you make  a function that sets the result then call it from the onBindViewHolder....Hope this work @T-lang